# Can a pronoun refer to a non-specific noun?

Tags: pronouns, indefinite-article

For example:

**A professor said that he loves teaching.**

Is it possible for "he" to refer to "a professor"?

Comment: It would hjelp us to give you a good answer if you explained why you think that something might be wrong with that sentence.

Comment: @JeremyC I'm assuming the sentence is correct. Though I figured that there was a chance that it wasn't correct because "a professor" is indefinite.

Comment: It's only a problem if the professor is a woman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is *absolutely nothing wrong* with that sentence. A personal pronoun (e.g. he, they, she, etc) can refer to a proper noun denoting a person, (e.g. John Smith, Mary Patel) or a non-specific one (a professor, my mother, the children, a manager, the chef). John Smith said that he likes beer. My mother said that she was tired. The children said that they wanted ice-cream. Mr Jones says he is thirsty. If a customer wants to speak to a manager, they (or "he or she") can phone after 10 o’clock. Peter complained to the chef about the meal. She wasn’t very helpful.

[Personal pronouns](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/personal-pronouns/)

[Pronouns: personal (I, me, you, him, it, they, etc.)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/pronouns-personal-i-me-you-him-it-they-etc)

Answer (score 0):

If a pronoun of definite gender appears in the same context as a noun of indefinite gender, without any change of context in-between, you can safely assume the pronoun refers back to the noun.  Otherwise this would be very confusing to English speakers.

Examples:

> The doctor calmly walked into the operating room.  "Is the patient sedated?" **she** (the doctor) asked the anesthesiologist.  "Yes, doctor," **he** (the anesthesiologist) replied.
>
> Although the senator repeatedly ran and was elected on a campaign of devout religious principle and scrupulous moral virtue, after **his** (the senator's) death, it was revealed **he** had as many as four illegitimate children.